# target_link_libraries adds unwanted optimization flag when compiling in Debug mode, how-to remove?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am including this external library https://github.com/S-Dafarra/alglib-cmake when compiling one of my projects.

In my CMakeLists.txt, I add link this library as PRIVATE:

```
find_package(ALGLIB REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(<target> PRIVATE ALGLIB)
```

When I compile my project in debug mode with `make VERBOSE=1`, I find an -O3 flag added to my (g++) compiler flags, that I would prefer to avoid.

Is someone aware of a way to 'remove it' with some specific command in the CMakeLists?

I tried printing COMPILE_OPTIONS or CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS*, but they do not contain this flag. In the original ALGLIB.cmake file, they are defined as:

```
INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "-O3;-DAE_OS=AE_POSIX;-pthread;-DAE_CPU=AE_INTEL"
```

Could I edit this property in my CMakeLists somehow? (I do not want to edit the original library). Thanks in advance.

If I remove the library from my project, or set it to INTERFACE instead of PRIVATE, then the O3 flag is gone.

Comment: You are right that `-O3` is a part of the library's project, it is added in [CMakeLists.txt:95](https://github.com/S-Dafarra/alglib-cmake/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L95). There is no 
"nice" way to remove this flag. You may edit either original project's `CMakeLists.txt` (and rebuild the library), or you may edit created `.cmake` file.

Comment: Well you can use the commands `get_property()` and `set_property()` to change the property of `INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS`.  I'm guessing the `ALGLIB.cmake` file creates an import library for the target `ALGLIB`. You could try to alter this property for the `ALGLIB` target after the call to `find_package()` and before `target_link_libraries()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your inputs.

I followed your suggestion and came up with this solution:

```
find_package(ALGLIB REQUIRED)

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL Debug)
    get_target_property(ICO ALGLIB INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS)
    string(REPLACE "-O3" "" ICO ${ICO})
    string(REPLACE "-" " -" ICO ${ICO})
    separate_arguments(ICO)
    set_target_properties(ALGLIB PROPERTIES INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "${ICO}")
endif()
```

Follow-up: https://github.com/S-Dafarra/alglib-cmake/issues/4